# Exception when casting from concrete class to interface in LINQ query

Tags: vb.net, linq, casting

I have a class SomeClass, which can populate itself from a datarow in it's constructor. This class implements IInterface. However, when I execute the code below:

```
Dim fpQuery As IEnumerable(Of IInterface) = _
    From dr As DataRow In DataLayer.SomeMethodToGetADataTable.AsEnumerable _
    Select New SomeClass(dr)
```

I get the error

```
Unable to cast object of type 
'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection`1[Classes.SomeClass]' 
to type
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Interfaces.IInterface]'
```

I should probably add that the following code works fine.

```
Dim fpQuery As IEnumerable(Of SomeClass) = _
    From dr As DataRow In DataLayer.SomeMethodToGetADataTable.AsEnumerable _
    Select New SomeClass(dr)
```

As does the simple cast

```
Dim myInterface As IInterface = New SomeClass(myDataRow)
```

Any ideas?

EDIT :
Jon Skeet got it spot on. I used the following code and it worked perfectly.

```
Dim fpQuery2 As IEnumerable(Of IInterface) = fpQuery.Cast(Of IInterface)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're running into a lack of variance in generics. To put it in a simpler example, you can't treat `IEnumerable(Of String)` as `IEnumerable(Of Object)`.

The simplest thing would probably be to add a call to [Cast(Of TResult)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx).